# C-x remapping in Vim

Tags: vim

I need to remap <kbd>C-x</kbd> in Vim to behave like in some Windows editors:

- In visual mode it should cut selected text.
- In normal mode it should cut the current line, only if it's not blank.
- A blank line should be deleted and put in the black hole registry.

Comment: Take a look at the mswin.vim that vim ships with.  You may just want to source that file and get even more Windows-like behaviors.

Comment: yeah, i know about the file. It contains this mapping `vnoremap <C-X> "+x` which takes care of point no.1 of what I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
" Source distribution script in $VIMRUNTIME directory
:runtime mswin.vim

if has('clipboard')
    nmap <silent> <C-X> :call CutNonEmptyLineToClipboard()<CR>
    " If the current line is non-empty cut it to the clipboard.
    " Else do nothing.
    function! CutNonEmptyLineToClipboard()
        if strlen(getline('.')) != 0
            normal 0"*D
        endif
    endfunction
endif
```

---

Updated version below. Had to google "black hole register", which I didn't know about. (Thanks!) I also put a different empty line matcher in. Pick the version that suits you best.

```
if has('clipboard')
    nmap <silent> <C-X> :call CutNonEmptyLineToClipboard()<CR>
    " If the current line is non-empty cut it out into the clipboard.
    " Else delete it into the black hole register (named _).
    function! CutNonEmptyLineToClipboard()
        " Test if the current line is non-empty
"       if strlen(getline('.')) != 0
        if match(getline('.'), '^\s*$') == -1
            normal 0"*D
        else
            normal "_dd
        endif
    endfunction
endif
```

Comment: Cool. It works fine, but it doesn't respect the last point ("A blank line should be deleted and put in the black hole registry"). It needs an `else normal "_dd` . If you edit the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @mihai Just a heads-up the Lumi updated their answer which seems to address your issue `:)`.